# *#9900# doesn't work in 2.3.3 any alternatives?

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have insufficient interval memory due to large system files. I have tried *#9900# but there is no option to delete the dump state or logcat files on 2.3.3.
What other methods can I use on a non rooted phone to achieve the same result?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I've just replaced your tag by the more fitting alternative (as the issue always relates to internal storage only, this one "obsoleted" the "internal-storage" tag). You might wish to see [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which contains a lot of hints and links to further information. Then come back here, and either answer your own question (if solved), or [edit] it to include what you've tried and where you're stuck. Thanks!